# Unable to refresh a xaml Contentpage cleanly with a large amount of items

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a logging page that adds logs while the application runs.
A feature that's required is the ability to autoscroll to the latest(last) added log.

The problem is that when I use the scrollto function on an observablecollection the logging page seems to reload the whole list.

This would not be an issue but when the list is large enough it causes the page to blink when redrawing the list.

Is there anyway add log statements to a page and scroll to the last element of the page without causing the page to blink.

**I'm up for any solution really but it must meet the requirements of:**

1. be able to refresh in real time when a log is created/added (which is frequently)
2. be able to automatically scroll to the end of the page.
3. be able to refresh cleanly(no blinking or other type of issue).

**My Attempts:**

I have tried two different ways to implement this.

The first way was adding a label of a "logstatement"(string) to a 
content page. I would then use a lastorDefault() method to find the last child in the layout(in this case a stacklayout) 
and then scroll to that item(in this case a Label()).

I have to add the label to the main thread by using Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(otherwise it conflicts with other aspects of the program) this causes a race condition between the scrolling function and this invocation which eventually throws an exception when the list is large enough.
The second issue with this way is that it also has this blinking issue when the page gets big enough and we're adding statements.

The second way i've tried implementing it is by using an observable collection in which I add labels to the observablecollection and use
a datatemplate to access the label's text and textcolor. I use the scrollto function to scroll to the bottom of the list after adding a label.
This works fine when the list is small (less than 150 or so) but afterwards the page blinks when adding labels(logstatements).

My current idea is to only have the last 50 or so items in the observable collection so the refresh is clean 
I'm looking for a better solution but maybe that does not exist.

I've heavily modified the code displayed so some of it won't make sense but I've tried to keep the logic pure here.

I am unable to add compilable code right now but I will create a test project if this code is insufficient please let me know.

Code:

```
    public LoggingPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        loggingPage.ItemAppearing += EnableAutoScroll;
        DisplayLogsOnScreen(logstatements);
    }

    //adds the logs to the screen
    private void DisplayLogsOnScreen(LogStatement logstatements)
    {
        Label loggingLabel = new Label();


        foreach (typeOfLog tempLogType in differentlogTypes)
        {
            switch (tempLogType)
            {
                case typeOfLog.FIRSTTYPE:
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                        logObservableCollection.Add(loggingLabel);
                    });
                    break;
                case LogType.SECONDTYPE:
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                        differentLogObservableCollection.Add(loggingLabel);
                    });
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }



   // have to wrap the scrollto events in an itemAppeared event handler 
   // otherwise the update to the UI is laggy
   // it still has issues updating the logview this workaround is not perfect

    private void AddAutoScroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (autoScroll)//a button that enables and disables autoscroll
            {
                logListView.ScrollTo(logObservableCollection.LastOrDefault(), ScrollToPosition.End, true);
                logListView.ScrollTo(differentLogObservableCollection.LastOrDefault(), ScrollToPosition.End, true);

            }
    }
```

Xaml:

```
<ContentPage Title="logPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView x:Name="loggingPage">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Text}" TextColor="{Binding TextColor}"/>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is the ListView's ScrollTo() function. When we call:

```
            logListView.ScrollTo(logObservableCollection.LastOrDefault(), ScrollToPosition.End, true);
```

The ScrollTo function seems to go through the entire observable collection to find the last item in the list.

I circumvented this by creating a method instead of using this onAppearing event handler.

Here is my updated code. Note that both have to be invoked on the main thread.

```
       if (statementObject.Types.Contains(LogType.diffLogType))
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                _incidentLabelListCollection.Add(logStatement);
                if (autoScroll)
                    EnableAutoScroll(logStatement,null);
            });
        }
```

second method

```
    private void EnableAutoScroll(Label label, ListView listView)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            if(logListView.IsVisible)
                logListView.ScrollTo(label, ScrollToPosition.End, false);

        });
    }
```